# Strange entry in Apache log

Tags: apache-2.2, log-files, intrusion-detection

in my [previous pos](https://serverfault.com/questions/215074/strange-stuff-in-apache-log)t I got something weird in Apache log. Again, I found something strange, but what freaks me out is the response code. It's not 501 anymore, but 200. What do you say? Should I enable the paranoid-mode? Here's the entry:

```
***.***.***.*** - - [02/Feb/2011:00:42:51 +0100] "=\xa29)\x84\x11\xd0O\xa7@\xbd\x8f\xc4G\x96T\xf4" 200 25564
```

Answer (score 3):

It wasn't a valid HTTP-request. You could get similar log entry doing something like `telnet youserver 80` and then *Entering* 'HELLO'. I guess there's some index.php at the root of your server?

Comment: That's right. There's an `index.php` in `/`.

Comment: So, it simply runs it as the default handler of the request. N0t4h4ck. )

Comment: Well, the IP originates from Ukraine. That's odd. =/

Comment: It's not odd, it's Interneted too.

Answer (score -1):

If memory serves 200 is a HTTP Status code for OK

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

From wikipedia

> 2xx Success
>
> This class of status codes indicates
>   the action requested by the client was
>   received, understood, accepted and
>   processed successfully.
>
> 200 OK
>       Standard response for successful HTTP requests. The actual response
>   will depend on the request method
>   used. In a GET request, the response
>   will contain an entity corresponding
>   to the requested resource. In a POST
>   request the response will contain an
>   entity describing or containing the
>   result of the action.

Comment: Yes, 200 = OK, but doesn't that mean that potentially malicious request is executed on my server?

Comment: I would think that this appearing in the log could be a simple misformed packet... as they do happen i dont often read my log files as close as you seem to :) (good on you tho for keep such a close eye on it) as an answer on your last post said if it woudl be more than likely that if this was a hacker that found a hole you would of been hacked well before you saw the log file. - I will however look around and see what i can find for you :)

Comment: have a look http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/logs.html#common it appears to be common place for a 200 in the logs, ill have a look at my apache server once i have a chance tomorrow

Comment: I'll do that, thanx for info!