# What are some specific changes you make when hardening a new NetBSD install?

Tags: hardening, netbsd

I know most of the general advice: "turn off unnecessary services", "no really, turn off unnecessary services", "least privilege", etc. I've also seen a few guides and/or tools, e.g., Bastille, for hardening Linux boxes, but nothing that seems tailored to NetBSD.

Assume for the sake of this list that I've already made sure `root` doesn't have SSH access, but that I haven't installed any server software.

What are your first steps for securing a new NetBSD box?

UPDATE: To be clear, I'm looking for specific steps. I'm entirely self-taught when it comes to server admin, but I feel I have a decent grasp of the general principles. I'm looking for details for two reasons:

1. To see if there is anything NetBSD-specific that I've overlooked.
2. To see if other people have better methods for putting the general principles into practice.

Thanks.

Comment: Also, check out ["Why should I firewall servers"](http://serverfault.com/questions/201298/why-should-i-firewall-servers). Lots of useful discussion about firewalls and security hardening in general.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please see [security(8)](http://netbsd.gw.com/cgi-bin/man-cgi?security%20%20NetBSD-current) in NetBSD manual. You can:

- Set **[securelevel](http://wiki-static.aydogan.net/Kernel_secure_levels)** in `rc.conf` to harden a production system
- Enable `security.curtain = 1` in *sysctl.conf* to limit users from seeing each other.
- Make relevant files *immutable* or *append only* with [chflags](http://netbsd.gw.com/cgi-bin/man-cgi?chflags%20%20NetBSD-5.0)
- Enable PaX **mprotect** and Address Space Layout Randomization (**aslr**) extensions in *sysctl.conf* (`security.pax.mprotect.global=1`, `security.pax.aslr.global=1`)
- Consider [Veriexec](http://www.netbsd.org/docs/guide/en/chap-veriexec.html) verified binaries

Please also see Elad Efrat's paper [Recent Security Enhancements in NetBSD](http://www.netbsd.org/~elad/recent/recent06.pdf).

Please note that features that prevent changing binaries also prevent you from upgrading the system so prepare to make upgrades in single user mode.

PaX extensions may prevent some software such as gnu make from working at all. You can leave the .global flags disabled and set PaX flags on binary basis with [paxctl](http://netbsd.gw.com/cgi-bin/man-cgi?paxctl%20%20NetBSD-5.0).

Answer (score 2):

It's the same with every system:

- Install and configure a firewall. Make it as restrictive as possible.
- Make sure the system is updated regularly
- Disable password login for ssh, only allow certificates
- Set up good logging and log-analyzing procedures.
- When setting up servers: If possible, but it behind bars (chroot jails)
- Don't install X11, a web browser or any non-server software (except it's a workstation, of course ...).
- Disconnect it from the network ;-)

Comment: Do you have specifics for things like "Set up good logging and log-analyzing procedures"?

Answer (score 1):

As SvenW said, the basic concepts pretty well apply across the board.

For a detailed read, the Center for Internet Security has a [Benchmark](http://cisecurity.org/en-us/?route=downloads.multiform) available for FreeBSD. I imagine that it should be fairly easy to translate to your environment.

Comment: I don't deal with the BSDs, so it should be interesting to see how well (if?) it works for you.