# Is a firewall really necessary?

Tags: security, debian, firewall

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Why should I firewall servers?](https://serverfault.com/questions/201298/why-should-i-firewall-servers)
>   [Why would I need a firewall if my server is well configured?](https://serverfault.com/questions/232642/why-would-i-need-a-firewall-if-my-server-is-well-configured)

For a single web server that only listens on 22/80/443, is a firewall (iptables) really necessary? What exactly is it protecting against if there are only two properly configured services listening on three ports?

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  It provides you with a buffer against incoming attacks and (which most people forget) outgoing malicious traffic, like reverse proxies, spam bots, etc., with the appropriate egress filtering, of course.

Comment: I don't know... *is it really necessary?* Necessary is one of those words that as a pedant I'd say no. But are you foolish to not run one, given the protection it offers with minimal hassle in maintenance and configuration? In my opinion, yes.